# Spring controller not returning valid JSON

Tags: java, json, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I have been trying to connect my backend (spring boot/java) with my frontend (Angular) but I keep getting this error in the console:

```
error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'S', "[Services {"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse,
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/providers/getServices"
```

My service looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ServiceSection } from 'src/app/models/services/service-section';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HomeItemService {

  private servicesUrl: string;
  private projectsUrl: string;
  // services: Observable<ServiceSection[]>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.servicesUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/providers/getServices';
    this.projectsUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/projects/getAllProjects'
  }

  public getAll(): Observable<ServiceSection[]> {
    console.log(this);
    return this.http.get<ServiceSection[]>(this.servicesUrl);
  }
}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
package hibera.web.api.controllers;

import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import hibera.web.api.domain.Services;
import hibera.web.api.service.FirebaseInit;
import hibera.web.api.service.ProvidingsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/providers")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class ProvidersController {
    @Autowired
    FirebaseInit db;
    @Autowired
    public ProvidingsService service;

    @GetMapping("/getServices")
    public String getServices() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        List<Services> services = new ArrayList<Services>();

        CollectionReference service = db.getFirebase().collection("services_section");
        ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot = service.get();

        for (DocumentSnapshot doc:querySnapshot.get().getDocuments()){
            Services serv = doc.toObject(Services.class);
            services.add(serv);
        }

        return services.toString();
    }
}
```

I understand that it is not being parsed as a json object but when I try to add `{responseType: 'text'}` it gives me a bunch of errors in the console. In postman all works fine, but trying to loop it the data from the database to the client gives me an actual headache. I honestly dont think it has anything to do with the API but rather the client.

I someone could have an answer for me or atleast help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you try hyphen or underscore instead camelCase as word delimiter in URIs?

Comment: Can you add whatever Postman returns for a call to http://localhost:8080/providers/getServices

Comment: @JohnWilliams I just posted the call return from post man as an answer!

Comment: The response received from the http://localhost:8080/providers/getServices is not valid JSON. The following is not valid JSON:  "Services {name ="'S'. As a minimum it should be "Services": {"name": . Hence the error "[Services {"... is not valid JSON. Try pasting it in a JSON validator site like https://jsonlint.com/ to confirm that it's not JSON. Note also that you missed the start of the JSON n your 'answer'. It should start with "[Services {". I will provide the fix in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your object to valid json with a Jackson `ObjectMapper` rather than do a `toString()`

`getServices` should return as follows:

```
return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(services);
```

You will need to autowire an `ObjectMapper` into `ProvidersController` as follows. `ObjectMapper` is dependent on `jackson-databind` but you probably have it via a dependency to `spring-boot-starter-web`

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper; // com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
```

Comment: @magicalassembler can you please change the question title to the more general: Spring controller not returning valid JSON

Comment: I will change the title!

Answer (score 1):

The `.toString()` method does not convert to proper JSON format.
As mentioned in the other answer, you can use any Json library to convert it into a JSON string.

But instead of returning String, you can return the object. Since it's a rest controller, it will convert the object into a JSON by default.

```
return services;
```

And in Angular, you can parse it normally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will remember that for next time

Comment: This does not compile. The method return type is String. The value being returned is a List<Services> services.

Comment: @JohnWilliams I have mentioned that return as list instead of string. So isn't it obvious that the method return type should be changed